# Unable to offset a Point3D in a Point3DCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to offset a point in a Point3DCollection but could not get it translated to the new position. The text box shows 0,0,0 for the first point though I am doing an offset of 3,3,3 to it. What is wrong with the following code:

```
var result = new Point3DCollection(n);

var pt1 = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);
var pt2 = new Point3D(5, 5, 5);

result.Add(pt1);
result.Add(pt2);  
result[0].Offset(3,3,3);
textbox1.Text = result[0].X + "," + result[0].Y + "," + result[0].Z;
```

Answer (score 1):

See under "remarks" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.point3d.offset.aspx

So result[0] does not give you a reference to the object but a copy, so that you change the offset of that copy and not the one in your collection.

If you need to work with a collection, one solution would be to replace your object in the collection and with a new Point3D object at the same index.